# Google maps. Dynamic load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

If there was no internet connection at that moment - program can't execute remote script and create `google` object. Later i'm trying to reload google maps script like this:

```
if($.isEmptyObject(google)) {
    $.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi?sensor=true', function () {
        google.load("maps", "3");                       
    });             
}
```

I'm getting this kind of message: `Google Maps API server rejected your request. within the sensor parameters must be set to true or false.` Why?

Answer (score 0):

> We've left the sensor parameter in this example as a variable true_or_false to emphasize that you **must** set this value to either true or false explicitly.

see here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

The sensor parameter is obligastory according to the reference.

Comment: Exactly. In the sample it has been set.

Comment: I think that I have to mention that I'm developing mobile application with phonegap and jquery mobile. Testing enviroment - Ripple Emulator. But I'm getting the same warning in real Android device.

Comment: did you try to set sensor:false just to get rid of the error message? It wont change the way the function works..

Comment: By the way, probably there should not be a semicolon after `google.load("maps", "3");`

Comment: Why do think so? I realy don't think that there is any influence due to semilicon.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($.isEmptyObject(google)) {
   $.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi', function () {
    google.load("maps", "3", {'other_params' : 'sensor=true' });                       
   });             
}
```

correct usage.

Comment: but now i'm getting blank white page after that piece of code executes.